# Android: TextInputLayout doesn’t fit into page and prevents the page from scrolling inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-textinputlayout, android-nestedscrollview

The structure of my layout file: Coordinator layout - NestedScrollView - Coordinator Layout - objects that i want to be able to scroll

My TextInputLayout with TextInputEditText is at the bottom of the screen and when filled, extends out of bounds of the screen. When I collapse the keyboard it’s still not scrollable.

Note: I don’t want to set maxLines to Edittext and make it scrollable itself. I want it to scroll with other elements.

However, if I put, for example, TextView at the bottom of the screen and it doesn’t fit, the page is scrollable. Any ideas?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
        
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
            <!--other items i want to scroll-->
            
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/descriptionLayout"
                android:layout_width="348dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="545dp"
                android:ems="16"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:hint="Add image description (optional)"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="256"
                app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_cloud_upload_24"
                android:textColor="#68B2A0"
                android:textColorHint="#68B2A0"
                app:hintTextColor="#68B2A0"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/titleLayout"
                app:boxStrokeErrorColor="#F75010"
                app:boxStrokeColor="#68B2A0"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
                app:errorIconTint="@color/error"
                app:errorTextColor="@color/error"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
                app:counterOverflowTextColor="@color/error"
                   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                app:counterTextColor="@color/main_green"
                >
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/descriptionTxt"
                    android:ems="16"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#68B2A0"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:maxLines="7"
                    />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    
    <!--bottom app bar-->
    
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you hard set `android:layout_marginTop="545dp"`. Try never to do that. Also i think use costaint layour in youre case is better. Just change `<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>` inside nested scroll view to `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>` and add this atributes:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent
```

If you need to show nested view in fullscteen, just chaange `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: changing coordinatorLayout to contraintLayout fixed it, thank you